# Camera flash is not working from uiimageviewcontroller ios

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

Does not blink any flash light -

```
-(void)_flashToggle
{
if (! [UIImagePickerController isFlashAvailableForCameraDevice:UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear ])
    return;

if (PickerController.cameraFlashMode == UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeOff)
    PickerController.cameraFlashMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeOn;
else
    PickerController.cameraFlashMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeOff;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily change the device torch mode by accessing it using `AVFoundation` framework like:

**Swift 3.0**

```
    func toggleTorchMode() {
    if let device = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo), device.hasTorch {
        let isTorchSupported = device.isTorchModeSupported(mode)
        let isTourchAvailable = device.isTorchAvailable
        if isTorchSupported && isTourchAvailable {
            do {
                try device.lockForConfiguration()
                if device.torchMode == AVCaptureTorchMode.on {
                    device.torchMode = AVCaptureTorchMode.off
                }
                else {
                    device.torchMode = AVCaptureTorchMode.on
                }
                device.unlockForConfiguration()
            } catch {
                Globals.printlnDebug("Error in setting the torch mode")
            }
        }
        else if mode == AVCaptureTorchMode.on{

            Globals.showErrorMessage("Torch not available", inViewController: self)
        }
    }
}
```

**Objective-C**

```
-(void)toggleTorchMode
{
    AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    if ((device) && (device.hasTorch) && (device.isTorchAvailable)) {
        [device lockForConfiguration:nil];
        if (device.torchMode == AVCaptureTorchModeOn) {
            device.torchMode = AVCaptureTorchModeOff;
        }
        else {
            device.torchMode = AVCaptureTorchModeOn;
        }
    }
    else {
        //ERROR: Device doesn't have tourch
    }
}
```

Comment: but i am using uiimagepickercontroller i want to implement using it not AVFoundation framework

Comment: and i want a flash mode not torch mode

Comment: UIImagePickerView opens the default camera view to capture and it have default control to manage the flash.